# Confused about joins

Tags: sql, join

I have the following sql structure

```
Department: id, name
Students: id,name
department_students: student_id, department_id
```

Find all departments with more than 10 students

Find all students that are not in tech department

How could I use join to get this?

Comment: Joins-Visual:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to join the tables together. Department to Department_students and then Students to Department_Students. Then in your WHERE clause you define further what you need to find. This is an example of "Find all students not in tech department"

```
 SELECT  S.ID, S.Name
FROM department_students AS DS
    INNER JOIN Department AS D
        ON DS.department_id = D.id
    INNER JOIN Students AS S
        ON S.ID = DS.student_id 
WHERE  
    D.Name <> 'Tech_Department'
```

Note: I am using MS SQL Server syntax.

So pretty much what you need to understand is that you are 'JOIN'ing the different tables to other tables 'ON' fields that have unique information (ie Keys). In your example the unique information that goes across the different tables is the "ID". Department ids to  department_students and then student ids to department_students.

Comment: This doesn't work. It finds the name of all students where that student is not ONLY in the tech department.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the terrible indentation

```
select *
from student s
where
    not exists 
    ( 
        select 1 
        from student_department sd 
        join department d
        on sd.student_id = s.id 
        and
        sd.department_id = d.id
        and
        d.name = 'tech'
    )



select d.name 
from department d
join student_department sd 
on d.id = sd.department_id 
group by sd.department_id
having count(*)>10
```